# Why does the word 'much' seem awkward in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

*I need to practice the piano *'a lot'* before the concert.*

Using 'a lot' vs 'much' sounds better, but how do I explain this since 'a lot' and 'much' can be used for uncountable items. Is it incorrect to use 'much' or is it just more common to use 'a lot'?